# What is the sum (or asymptotic behavior of partial sum) of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n}$ where $0<a<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $0<a<1$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a^{n}}/{n}$ is summable as
$${a^{n}}/{n}\leq a^{n}$$ and the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n}$ converges to ${a}/{(1-a)}$.

Can we compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a^{n}}/{n}$
explicitly ?
At least what is the asymptotic behavior  of
$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{a^{n}}/{n}$ as $N\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for the logarithm?

Comment: $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-+...$. So ?

Comment: By integrating $\frac{a}{1-a}$ in $a$, you will recover the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: Now set $x=-a$ ….

Comment: @ Martin R. The sum is neither $\log{(1-a)}$ nor $\log{(1+a)}$.

Comment: @Didier. That is it. (+1)

Comment: @Medo: $\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}- \cdots$ is very close to what you want.

Comment: @medo Are you looking for a closed-form solution of the series?  It is $-\log(1-a)$.  Or are you looking for an asymptotic (large $N$) expansion of the finite sum?  That can be found using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.

Comment: @Martin R  $-\log{(1-a)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}a^n/n$ is close. Interesting, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a^n $

Then

$S(n) = \dfrac{a}{1 - a} $

Therefore,

$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^a \sum_{n = 1}^\infty t^n \ dt = \int_{0}^a \dfrac{t}{1 - t} \ dt $

The left hand side is

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a^n}{n} - a $

The right hand side is integrable using the substitution $ u = 1 - t$

$ \displaystyle \int_0^a \dfrac{t}{1 - t} dt = \int_1^{1 - a} - \dfrac{1 - u}{u} du = \int_{1 - a}^1 \bigg( \dfrac{1}{u} - 1 \bigg) \ du = - \ln(1 - a) - a $

Therefore,

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a^n}{n} = - \ln(1 - a) $

Answer (score 0):

As @ Didier pointed out:

We have

$$-\log{(1-a)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n}.$$

Comment: Why give someone's comment as your own answer?

Comment: @coffeemath The policy (such as it is) is that comments are not for answers.  If someone posts an answer in the comments, then anyone  else is permitted to post that comment as an answer.  It is polite to give credit (as was done here), but the general philosophy of this site is to discourage too much ownership of the material  posted (though Math SE does protect personal ownership more than other sites in the SE network).

Comment: @XanderHenderson OK thanks (didn't know the policy).